# How to patch a FastAPI Request

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I have this function that is called as a dependency in all of my APIs.

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException, Request, status


async def get_user_id_or_401(request: Request) -> str:
    user_id: str = request.headers.get("x-cognito-user-id")

    if not user_id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorized"
        )
    return user_id
```

How do I unit test this function? My initial move was to patch `request.headers.get` but i don't know how to go about that.

So, my question is, how do I patch `request.headers.get`. However, if there is a better way I can go about testing this, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats what overrides are for https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

Something like this:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app


client = TestClient(app)

async def mock_user_id(request):
    return "foo"

app.dependency_overrides[get_user_id_or_401] = mock_user_id

def test_request():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

But I think it would be better to make the requests during test such that this isn't required by adding the header to it. That would also test your function there, which is otherwise not covered.

```py
def test_request():
    response = client.get("/", headers={"x-cognito-user-id": "foo"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

---

If you want to unit test your user id function, you could import it into your test file and instantiate some mock requests.

Note, the header keys and values should be bytes. So the type of headers is like `list[tuple[byte, byte]]`.

```py
from starlette import status
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException
from starlette.requests import Request


def get_user_id_or_401(request: Request) -> str:
    user_id: str = request.headers.get("x-cognito-user-id")

    if not user_id:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorized"
        )
    return user_id


def test_uid():
    r = Request(scope={
        "type": "http",
        "headers": [("x-cognito-user-id".encode(), "foo".encode())],
    })
    assert get_user_id_or_401(r) == "foo"
```

Comment: You are instead mocking `get_user_id_or_401` which is what I actually want to test. The idea is not to test the api request. But to test this `get_user_id_or_401` function which happens to be called as a dependency. Sure, I'll use dependency overrides to mock this function but in this case, I don't want to mock it, I want to test it independently

Comment: @EyongKevinEnowanyo, so import it into your unit test file and call it, passing in some dummy requests that you instantiate yourself in the test.

Comment: please show code example. Because I did and it didn't work

Comment: @EyongKevinEnowanyo, I can put something together, but I need to go do something first. I will tag you once I have updated my answer.

Comment: @EyongKevinEnowanyo, I have updated my answer with a basic example how to mock the request with headers.